# Connection refused for application hosted over docker swarm

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have a docker swarm running on 2 nodes created via `Oracle VirtualBox` installed on `CentOS 7`. I am able to deploy a stack running 6 containers equally distributed over the two machines.

However, I am unable to connect to the deployed application with ports exposed.

Here's the content of my `Docker Compose File`

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: <myusername>/friendlyhello:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 6
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Here is the output of `docker-machine ls`:

```
NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
myvm1   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.09.0
myvm2   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v18.09.0
```

Here is the error from my `curl` command

```
curl http://192.168.99.100/
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.99.100:80; Connection refused
```

Even though my application seems to be running fine.

```
docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                              PORTS
i5nw2wcir9j3        getstartedlab_web   replicated          6/6                 harmanspall/friendlyhello:latest   *:80->80/tcp

docker service ps getstartedlab_web
ID                  NAME                  IMAGE                              NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
dn7mrfo1yvg4        getstartedlab_web.1   harmanspall/friendlyhello:latest   myvm1               Running             Running 28 minutes ago
jxkr1psbvmpc        getstartedlab_web.2   harmanspall/friendlyhello:latest   myvm2               Running             Running 28 minutes ago
jttd4t6b9gz5        getstartedlab_web.3   harmanspall/friendlyhello:latest   myvm1               Running             Running 28 minutes ago
zhs0c7ygj8cs        getstartedlab_web.4   harmanspall/friendlyhello:latest   myvm2               Running             Running 28 minutes ago
mx6gykk3qocd        getstartedlab_web.5   harmanspall/friendlyhello:latest   myvm1               Running             Running 28 minutes ago
pku7f60ij0bq        getstartedlab_web.6   harmanspall/friendlyhello:latest   myvm2               Running             Running 28 minutes ago
```

My Docker network list, as seen from Swarm Manager:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                   DRIVER              SCOPE
5c502a957a70        bridge                 bridge              local
a3b1f749c09f        docker_gwbridge        bridge              local
80nens8mmp6i        getstartedlab_webnet   overlay             swarm
c9647a0f6c30        host                   host                local
mj60zgzhiwjf        ingress                overlay             swarm
5adba823ce78        none                   null                local
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

~~ EDIT ~~
This does not seem to be an issue with connectivity to VMs since I am able to ping my Virtualbox

```
ping 192.168.99.100 -c 5
PING 192.168.99.100 (192.168.99.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.99.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.246 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.99.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.215 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.99.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.226 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.99.100: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.251 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.99.100: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.262 ms

--- 192.168.99.100 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.215/0.240/0.262/0.017 ms
```

It also fails when I try curl from inside the VM

```
docker-machine ssh myvm1 "curl http://192.168.99.100/"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 80: Connection refused
exit status 7

docker-machine ssh myvm1 "curl http://localhost/"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
exit status 7
```

Comment: docker-machine ls only shows that there are two VMs running where your containers could run. You should give us the output of "docker service ps" tells more about the deployed services' state.

Comment: How is networking configured in virtualbox? Can you ping the two VM's? My guess is that you have NAT configured in Virtualbox. You should try to switch to bridged.

Comment: @Markus I just added the info.

Comment: @IlyasDeckers It's bridged, I believe. Posted in the original thread. I actually tried to use curl from inside the Virtualbox too and the results was same. And ping to Virtualbox succeeds.

Comment: does your image  <myusername>/friendlyhello:latest expose the port?

Comment: It does via `Dockerfile` EXPOSE 80

Comment: What OS is running on your VirtualBox?  There is an issue with connectivity to the current boot2docker image: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4608 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356557/unable-to-reach-web-server-in-docker-swarm-from-the-host

Comment: @nachbar I think I am encountering the same issue, since I was able to make it work when I connected two physical machines. This was basically a problem with OracleBox.